# How to integrate PjSip in Swift project?

Tags: ios, swift, voip, pjsip

[image]I want to integrate the PJSIP in my project , I am following the steps give site (https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone). I am able to make a project as they told . but know I want to integrate in my swift project . Can anyone guide me , how to integrate PJSIP library and other code in my Code . Right now ,I am facing a linker errors in my swift object.

Comment: What kind of linking errors are you facing? To my knowledge you can bridge all the headers to Swift and just call the C calls. If not write your own wrapper methods in Obj-C and call those in Swift. These low-level C project might need a hand when used in a Swift-only project.

Comment: Well , I added the library that is generated by the Terminal as above given site . There I got struck ,

Comment: Are you running it on your simulator? Because this looks like the library is just not built for the interface you're running it on. Try to run it on an actual device if you can.

Comment: The question is too wide, you need to be more specific and describe the problem in detail. Including: 1. The version of PJSIP, 2. Flags Passed for the build, 3. Aditional libraries used like OpenSSL, OpenH264 etc,  4. For which Architectures did you build, 5. A testing device for your App, 6. Process of importing Libraries and headers, 7. Other settings step by step. I just built my Swift project with PJSIP 2.7.2

Comment: Were you able to implement it for Swift Project? I also want to integrate pjsip into my app. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @RatneshwarSingh Please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68159239/1971013) below.

Answer (score 3):

This is from my notes of a project that uses PJSIP and should cover everything to set up a new Xcode project:

```
- Download from https://www.pjsip.org/download.htm

- Info:
    https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone
    https://onmyway133.com/posts/learning-voip-rtp-and-sip-aka-awesome-pjsip/
    
- Create ./pjproject-2.10/pjlib/include/pj/config_site.h:
    #define PJ_CONFIG_IPHONE 1
    #define PJMEDIA_HAS_VIDEO 1
    #define PJMEDIA_HAS_VID_TOOLBOX_CODEC 1

    #define PJ_HAS_SSL_SOCK 1
    #define PJ_SSL_SOCK_IMP PJ_SSL_SOCK_IMP_APPLE

    #include <pj/config_site_sample.h>

- Create ./pjproject-2.10/user.mak:
    export LDFLAGS += -framework Network -framework Security -framework VideoToolbox

- In ./pjproject-2.10 run:
    $ export MIN_IOS="-miphoneos-version-min=13.0"
    $ ./configure-iphone
    $ make dep && make clean && make

- Add Network, Security, and VideoToolbox (for H264) iOS frameworks to Xcode project.

- Create <your app name>-Bridging-Header.h and mark it as Objective-C Bridging Header in Build Settings:
    #import "pjsua.h"
    ...

- Add PJ_AUTOCONF to Build Settings > Preprocessor Macros

- Add/Drag the .a files from the following directories to General > Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content:
    ./pjproject-2.10/pjlib/lib/
    ./pjproject-2.10/pjlib-util/lib/
    ./pjproject-2.10/pjmedia/lib/
    ./pjproject-2.10/pjnath/lib/
    ./pjproject-2.10/pjsip/lib/

- Add the following directories to Build Settings > Header Search Paths (use relative path from app's main directory):
    ./pjproject-2.10/pjlib/include/
    ./pjproject-2.10/pjlib-util/include/
    ./pjproject-2.10/pjmedia/include/
    ./pjproject-2.10/pjnath/include/
    ./pjproject-2.10/pjsip/include/
```

Comment: Thanks for this, just to note. Under Build Settings > Library Search Path, remember to add `/third_party/lib` path, too. For example: `"$(SRCROOT)/SIP_test_new/PJSua2/pjsip/third_party/lib"`

Comment: Good addition @VinhNguyen indeed; the things I show must be repeated for all libraries you use.

Comment: @meaning-matters I follow all step which is mention in answer but I’m facing “undefined symbols for architecture arm64”. Please help me.

Comment: One another question is downloaded folder is put in project folder or not. Should I add only lib file and header path in build settings?@meaning-matters and @vijayvir sing pantila

Comment: @SBK How you organise files is up to you.

Comment: I integrate Pjsip but outgoing call is not working just audio is play user is not available in server side but incoming call is working from same server. Please help me

Comment: @SBK Post a question with details. But I can tell you upfront that your kind of issue is going to be very hard to get help with via SO, because there are many possible causes that often require live access to figure out. Best would probably be to ask in the PJSIP forum. Good luck!